# Is there a way to have a Running Sum not begin with 1, but a certain value?

Tags: ms-access, cumulative-sum

I have two sub reports that help to split a certain set of records up based on user selected combo boxes. I want the second subreport to start a running sum at the end of the first subreport. They are each driven by their own queries that pulls from the same tables and queries with different criteria.

I tried a counter module that I saw from a different post but the problem is that every time the user scrolls or clicks on a box in the report, the numbers in the counter field change.

Below is the entire module,

```
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit

Dim mlngCounter As Long

Function ZeroCounter() 
  mlngCounter = 0
  ZeroCounter = 0
End Function

Function GetCounter(pvar As Variant)
  mlngCounter = mlngCounter + 1
  GetCounter = mlngCounter
End Function
```

Below is the equation I use in the query to call up the module in the first field.

```
Expr1: GetCounter([qryEditCuttingToolsRelation]![SetupID])+ZeroCounter()
```

qryEditCuttingToolsRelation is a filtered query from a table, and I want it to count up based on the unique SetupID. The output is correct as soon as I open the query or report. But as soon as I select anything or scroll on either the report or the query, the entire column of numbers increases.

Comment: Your setup is not clear.  The explanation in the first paragraph does not seem to mesh with the later details.  You say "below is the equation in the query to call up the module in the first field", but what query are you talking about and what do you mean by "call up the module"?  The idea seems to be a running sum, but your example is labeled "Expr1".  Is that field intended to be the running sum you're talking about?  You attempted to explain `qryEditCuttingToolsRelation![SetupID]`, but you did not explain precisely how it relates to the "last record" of the "first subreport".

Comment: Also, I don't see how the output would ever be correct unless only coincidental.  `GetCounter()` does not even use the value of `[qryEditCuttingToolsRelation]![SetupID]` which is passed in.  It looks like it would start at 1 and continually be reset to 0 each time in the call to `ZeroCounter()`.  Because you didn't share the "different post" where you got the counting technique, it's difficult to understand the intended result.  Access might re-query individual fields or rows when it redraws portions of a report or query, so a counter function may be called out of order as you observed.

Comment: Thanks for replying quickly. Honestly I am new to Ms access and even newer to VBA so my knowledge is very limited. I am not committed at all on using this method, this was just the closest I have come to finding any solution at all. I did not fully understand what the original post I saw was trying to do, but i got results that were close so I continued with it. Do you have any recommendations for a possible different approach?

Comment: Essentially all I am trying to do is start a running sum after the end of a numbered set of data. I have X amount of tools used for any given job in the shop, Some tools are universal and have generic numbers in our machines. Other tools we use are custom and do not have a generic number. I would like my custom tools section to begin directly after that last number used on the standard tools. 
Example: Standard tools used may be 1, 3, 6, and 14. So I want my custom tools to be automatically numbered 15, 16, 17.... 
The standard tools change so I did not want to hard code a start if possible.

Comment: As I perceive your requirements, it really is a matter of distinct steps, all of which are beyond the scope of this particular questions.  The title question itself seems reasonable, but trying to answer in context of the details you shared is difficult to reconcile.  Perhaps we can continue this discussion in chat.  One primary question I have is whether the generated list of numbers needs to be stored and/or reproducible?  In other words, if you run the same report tomorrow and the list of previous tools has been edited, should the second subreport generate an entirely new set of numbers?

Comment: Through the help of a coworker, I found the answer on another forum. Thank you very much for all of your help. Sorry that I am new and not fully aware of how to word these types of questions in a way they can be answered efficiently and easily.